# Creating a leaderboard

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, leaderboard

I have https://zaivlife.com/games, that is a backend on my ZAI UNIVERSE android app. I want to create a leaderboard for the users that have the most referals. I am pretty new to this so i will like to ask some help. First issue I don't have in database a row with total numbers of referals of an user. In code number is extracted like this:

```
//============================ Total user referral
function total_user_referral($table, $user_id){
    $this->db->select($user_id);
    $this->db->where('user_referral', $user_id);
    $q = $this->db->get($table);
    return $q->num_rows();

}
```

Full user_model.php file:

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {

//============================ Main construct
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // Your own constructor code
}

//============================ Check if username exist or not
function check_username($table, $user_username){
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_username' => $user_username));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

//============================ Check if email exist or not
function check_email($table, $user_email){
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_email' => $user_email));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

//============================ Check any users exist in the role table
function check_user_exist_in_role($table, $user_role_id){
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_role_id' => $user_role_id));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

//============================ Check if any content exist in user
function check_content_exist($table, $user_id){
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, array('content_user_id' => $user_id));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

//============================ Check if email exist or not
function check_mobile($table, $user_mobile){
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_mobile' => $user_mobile));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

//============================ Check if referral ID exist or not
function check_referral($table, $user_referral){
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_id' => $user_referral));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

//============================ Authentication user login with user_username OR user_email
function auth_user_information($table, $user_username, $user_password){
    //Login with Username
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_username'=>$user_username, 'user_password'=>$user_password));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return true;

    else { //Login with Email
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_email'=>$user_username, 'user_password'=>$user_password));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

//============================ Authentication user login
function compare_old_new_password($table, $user_id, $old_password){
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'user_password'=>$old_password));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//============================ Read user information with user_username OR user_email
function read_user_information($table, $user_username){
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_username'=>$user_username));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query->result();

    else {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_email'=>$user_username));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return $query->result();
        else
            return false;
    }

}

//============================ User role
function get_users_list2($table){
    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_type_table.user_type_title, user_role_table.user_role_title, device_type_table.device_type_title
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN user_type_table
                            ON user_table.user_type = user_type_table.user_type_id 
                            INNER JOIN user_role_table
                            ON user_table.user_role_id = user_role_table.user_role_id
                            INNER JOIN device_type_table
                            ON user_table.user_device_type_id = device_type_table.device_type_id
                            ORDER BY user_id desc");
    return $q;
}

//============================ Reset password
public function reset_password_process($user_email, $new_user_password)
{
    $data = array(
        'user_password' => $new_user_password
    );
    $this->db->where('user_email', $user_email);
    if ($this->db->update('user_table', $data))
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

//============================ Get user information with user_id
function get_user_content($table, $user_id){
    $query = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_type_table.user_type_title, user_role_table.user_role_title, device_type_table.device_type_title
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN user_type_table
                            ON $table.user_type = user_type_table.user_type_id 
                            INNER JOIN user_role_table
                            ON $table.user_role_id = user_role_table.user_role_id 
                            INNER JOIN device_type_table
                            ON $table.user_device_type_id = device_type_table.device_type_id 
                            WHERE user_id = $user_id;");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query;

    else{
        //Clear session
        unset(
            $_SESSION['user_id'],
            $_SESSION['user_username'],
            $_SESSION['user_email'],
            $_SESSION['user_mobile'],
            $_SESSION['user_role_id'],
            $_SESSION['user_type']
        );

        $msg = $this->lang->line("Successfully Logout!");
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',$msg);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msgType','success');
        redirect(base_url().'dashboard/Auth');
        $this->db->close();
        die();
    }
}

//============================ Get user image with user_id
function get_user_image($table, $user_id){
    $this->db->select('user_image');
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('user_id'=>$user_id));
        return $query->result()[0];
}

//============================ Get user activity with user_id
function get_user_activity($table, $user_id, $limit){
    $this->db->order_by('activity_id DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('activity_user_id' => $user_id), $limit);
    return $query;
}

//============================ Total user referral
function total_user_referral($table, $user_id){
    $this->db->select($user_id);
    $this->db->where('user_referral', $user_id);
    $q = $this->db->get($table);
    return $q->num_rows();

}

//============================ Total user games
function total_user_games($table, $user_id){
    $this->db->select($user_id);
    $this->db->where('content_user_id', $user_id);
    $q = $this->db->get($table);
    return $q->num_rows();
}

//============================ User type (Account type)
function get_user_type($table){
    $this->db->order_by('user_type_id ASC');
    return $q = $this->db->get($table);
}

//============================ User role
function get_user_role($table, $user_type_id){
    if(isset($user_type_id))
        $where = "WHERE $table.user_type_id = '$user_type_id'";
    else
        $where = "";
    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_type_table.*
                            FROM user_role_table
                            INNER JOIN user_type_table
                            ON user_role_table.user_type_id = user_type_table.user_type_id 
                            $where
                            ORDER BY user_role_id ASC;");
    return $q;
}

//============================ User role for upgrade account
function get_user_role_for_upgrade($table){
    $current_user_role_id = $_SESSION['user_role_id'];
    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*
                            FROM $table
                            WHERE (user_type_id = 2) AND (user_role_id != 5) AND (user_role_id != $current_user_role_id)
                            ORDER BY user_role_id ASC;");
    return $q;
}

//============================ Get role from type
public function get_role_from_type($user_type_id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_type_id', $user_type_id);
    $this->db->order_by('user_type_id', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('user_role_table');
    $select = $this->lang->line("--- Please Select ---");
    $output = '<option disabled>'.$select.'</option>';
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row->user_role_id.'">'.$row->user_role_title.'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

//============================ Get user information with user_id
function get_user_role_content($table, $user_role_id){
    $query = $this->db->query("Select $table.*
                            FROM $table
                            WHERE user_role_id = $user_role_id;");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query;
    else
        return false;
}

//============================ Ajax all users count
function all_users_count()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('user_table');
    return $query->num_rows();
}

//============================ Ajax all users list
function all_users($limit,$start,$col,$dir)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("Select user_table.*, user_type_table.user_type_title, user_role_table.user_role_title, device_type_table.device_type_title
                            FROM user_table
                            INNER JOIN user_type_table
                            ON user_table.user_type = user_type_table.user_type_id 
                            INNER JOIN user_role_table
                            ON user_table.user_role_id = user_role_table.user_role_id
                            INNER JOIN device_type_table
                            ON user_table.user_device_type_id = device_type_table.device_type_id
                            ORDER BY $col $dir 
                            LIMIT $start, $limit;");
    //$query = $this->db->limit($limit,$start)->order_by($col,$dir)->get('user_table');
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
        return $query->result();
    else
        return null;
}

//============================ Ajax users search
function users_search($limit,$start,$search,$col,$dir)
{
    /*$query = $this
        ->db
        ->like('user_username',$search)
        ->or_like('user_firstname',$search)
        ->or_like('user_lastname',$search)
        ->or_like('user_email',$search)
        ->limit($limit,$start)
        ->order_by($col,$dir)
        ->get('user_table');*/

    $query = $this->db->query("Select user_table.*, user_type_table.user_type_title, user_role_table.user_role_title, device_type_table.device_type_title
                            FROM user_table
                            INNER JOIN user_type_table
                            ON user_table.user_type = user_type_table.user_type_id 
                            INNER JOIN user_role_table
                            ON user_table.user_role_id = user_role_table.user_role_id
                            INNER JOIN device_type_table
                            ON user_table.user_device_type_id = device_type_table.device_type_id
                            WHERE ((user_username LIKE '%$search%') OR (user_firstname LIKE '%$search%') OR (user_lastname LIKE '%$search%') OR (user_email LIKE '%$search%')
                            OR (user_type_title LIKE '%$search%') OR (user_role_title LIKE '%$search%') OR (device_type_title LIKE '%$search%')) 
                            ORDER BY $col $dir 
                            LIMIT $start, $limit;");

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
        return $query->result();
    else
        return null;
}


//============================ Ajax users count
function users_search_count($search)
{
    $query = $this
        ->db
        ->like('user_username',$search)
        ->or_like('user_firstname',$search)
        ->or_like('user_lastname',$search)
        ->or_like('user_email',$search)
        ->get('user_table');

    return $query->num_rows();
}


//============================ Users activity
function get_all_activity($table, $limit){
    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_table.user_username, user_table.user_id
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN user_table
                            ON $table.activity_user_id = user_table.user_id 
                            ORDER BY activity_id DESC
                            LIMIT $limit;");
    return $q;
}


//============================ Get transactions list
function get_transactions($table, $user_id)
{
    //Check Staff or User
    if($user_id == 'staff')
    {
        $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, gateway_table.gateway_name, user_table.user_id, user_table.user_firstname, user_table.user_lastname
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN gateway_table
                            ON $table.transaction_gateway = gateway_table.gateway_id
                            INNER JOIN user_table
                            ON $table.transaction_user_id = user_table.user_id
                            ORDER BY transaction_id DESC;");
    }else{
        $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, gateway_table.gateway_name, user_table.user_id, user_table.user_firstname, user_table.user_lastname
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN gateway_table
                            ON $table.transaction_gateway = gateway_table.gateway_id
                            INNER JOIN user_table
                            ON $table.transaction_user_id = user_table.user_id
                            WHERE transaction_user_id = $user_id
                            ORDER BY transaction_id DESC;");
    }

    return $q;
}


//============================ Get transaction content with transaction_id
function get_transaction_content($table, $transaction_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_table.user_firstname, user_table.user_lastname, user_table.user_id, gateway_table.gateway_name
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN user_table
                            ON $table.transaction_user_id = user_table.user_id 
                            INNER JOIN gateway_table
                            ON $table.transaction_gateway = gateway_table.gateway_id 
                            WHERE transaction_id = $transaction_id;");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query;
    else
        return false;
}


//============================ Get user credit
function get_user_credit($table, $user_id){
    $query = $this->db->query("Select $table.user_credit
                            FROM $table
                            WHERE user_id = $user_id;");
    return $query;

}


//============================ Update user credit
function update_user_credit($table, $amount, $user_id, $type){
    /*
     * Type +: Add Funds
     * Type -: Decrease Funds
     */
    if($type == "+") {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $table SET user_credit = user_credit + $amount WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");

    }elseif($type == "-") {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $table SET user_credit = user_credit - $amount WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
    }
}


//============================ Comments count
public function get_total_comments_count($table, $keyword, $comment_status) {

    $where = "WHERE comment_status = '$comment_status'";
    if($keyword != "")
        $where = "WHERE comment_text LIKE '%$keyword%'";

    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*
                            FROM $table
                            $where
                            ;");
    return $q->num_rows();
}


//============================ Comments List
function get_comments($table, $keyword, $comment_status, $limit, $start)
{
    $where = "WHERE comment_status = '$comment_status'";
    if($keyword != "")
        $where = "WHERE comment_text LIKE '%$keyword%'";

    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_table.user_username, user_table.user_id, device_type_table.device_type_title, content_table.content_title, content_table.content_id
                            FROM $table
                            INNER JOIN user_table
                            ON $table.comment_user_id = user_table.user_id 
                            INNER JOIN device_type_table
                            ON $table.comment_device_type_id = device_type_table.device_type_id 
                            INNER JOIN content_table
                            ON $table.comment_content_id = content_table.content_id 
                            $where
                            ORDER BY comment_id DESC
                            LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start;");
    return $q;
}

//============================ Get one comment
function get_one_comment($table, $comment_id)
{
    $q = $this->db->query("Select $table.*, user_table.user_username, user_table.user_id, device_type_table.device_type_title, content_table.content_title, content_table.content_id
                        FROM $table
                        INNER JOIN user_table
                        ON $table.comment_user_id = user_table.user_id 
                        INNER JOIN device_type_table
                        ON $table.comment_device_type_id = device_type_table.device_type_id 
                        INNER JOIN content_table
                        ON $table.comment_content_id = content_table.content_id 
                        WHERE comment_id = '$comment_id'
                        ;");
    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        return $q->result()[0];
    else
        redirect(base_url()."dashboard/User/comments_list");
}
```

Now I created an row in that table named `total _referals`.... I can't find a way to insert the result of this code...the return..num_rows in that row. Thanks you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very good at CodeIgniter.
I reviewed the documents. (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

You should use

```
$builder->countAll();
```

after select your table, column and where.
Regards

EDIT: I didn't know you are using CodeIgniter3. And you have changed your question content after I answered.
So you can use this guide:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results
And my new answer:

```
$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->like('user_referral', $user_id); 
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: The builder class and the link you provided are for Codeigniter 4. This question is explicitly for Codeigniter 3.

Comment: I arranged my answer. The initial version of the problem was not so revealing.

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much for help. I have those lines in script already. Because in dashboard user can see how many refferals have. But the script is not inserting this result in database. In user table was no row for that to be stored. In order to create a leaderboard i need this results to be in database...to be able to extract after in leaderboard. I created a new row manualy in database table: user_table...and i named total_refferals....now i whant the script to insert the result of that rowcount in that database row...after that i will extract in leaderboard..thank you